# Is there any way to restart the Tiny Death Star Holiday Decoration Event?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

The Holiday Decoration Event may have started a month ago, but, it only showed up yesterday in my game.  And, it says there are 0 days left. The app was updated as soon as it was released, but there was no sign of it in-game. Is this a bug? If so, are there any fixes that I can apply?

Answer (score 2):

Did you update your app when the decoration event was first started about a month ago? That may have caused the issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: This answer should be a comment. But, you are correct. The issue is most likely a lack of updating the app.

Comment: Thanks guys. The app was updated when the update came out. And I checked the re checked it a week later, so it's not that..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything you can do about this.  The event has ended, and there doesn't appear to be any way to reactivate it.

The only recourse you might have:  email Disney customer support and explain the bug to them.  support@disneymobile.com

If you click on the menu button and choose the wrench, and then click the help tab you will see long string of numbers.  If you include this set of numbers, they may be able to help you.